# Output <hr> in email message php

Tags: php, html, email

How can I output a thematic break (< hr>) in my email message sent using the php mail() function. In the email, it appears as < hr> itself instead of a thematic break.

Comment: r u saying horizontal bar'

Comment: you need to set the headers to say its html email, and include the appropriate html, example 4 in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: sent your email as HTML and not as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Check out example 4:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Fair criticism - but I like to give as complete an answer as possible and not make people go to multiple pages if they're just looking for an answer.  And in this case, the example was exactly what they needed.

Comment: well a comment with a link would of been sufficient, oh like I did before your 'answer' :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML in your email send with mail(), you have to add a Content-type header to state that the email should be parsed as HTML. Please see example 4 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php