# How to add <hr> in php mail form?

Tags: php

I want to add a horizontaly line

---

inside a form content in php. Is that possible?

I write the code below but 'hr' looks like that in my email
PR1: product1
PR2: product2 < hr >
PR3: product3
PR4: product4

What should I do? Thanks !!!

```
   <?php
    $product1= $_POST['product1'];
    $product2= $_POST['product2'];
    $product3 = $_POST['product3'];
    $product4 = $_POST['product4'];
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
  $formcontent=" From: $name \n ST1: $product1 \n PR2: $product2 <hr> \n PR3: $product3 \n PR1: $product4";
    
    $recipient = "form@mycompany.com";
    $subject = "My Products";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I have never used the php mail library but my guess is that your email type was marked as text. If you want it to display properly, you need to mark it as html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output <hr> in email message php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235341/output-hr-in-email-message-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<hr/>` tag in your email body, you should use HTML email format, which means adding HTML tags and Content-type headers.

You can try this one

```php
  <?php
    $product1= $_POST['product1'];
    $product2= $_POST['product2'];
    $product3 = $_POST['product3'];
    $product4 = $_POST['product4'];
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
  $formcontent="<html><body> From: $name \n ST1: $product1 \n PR2: $product2 <hr> \n PR3: $product3 \n PR1: $product4 </body></html>";
    
    $recipient = "form@mycompany.com";
    $subject = "My Products";
    $mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I think this answer would be much stronger if you added some comments about what you changed and why you think changing it will solve the issue.

Comment: No, it doesnt work, it looks like that now...<html><body> From:  
PR1: Product1
 PR2: Product2 </hr>
 PR3: Product3  PR4: Product4 </html></body>

Comment: @ric12g  When I checked my suggested code, it was correctly formatted. I guess you forgot to edit `$mailheader` section.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it doesn't work .. any other suggestion?? thanks..

Comment: @ric12g Would it be possible to attach a screenshot of the email you received?

Comment: All right I just find the issue... (text/html) I forgot it to plain.. All works fine now!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

put content below or above following div

```
<div style='width:100%; height : 13px; float:left; border-bottom : 1px solid black;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I don't understant ..Where to add this?? in which line in php mail form?

Comment: see this called as HTML Mail , checkout formats available on internet